# Android-- PhoneGap/WebView ignores viewport meta tags?

Tags: android, html, webview, cordova

I have a webpage that I'm trying to display on my Android device (loaded from the assets directory of the project) using PhoneGap (which uses a normal WebView set as the "appview"), but the webview completely ignores the following:

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
```

No matter what I set in this line (I've tried explicitly setting the zoom, setting the width/height in pixels, etc.), the device completely ignores it and renders the website very small and anchored to the upper left-hand corner of the screen. I can zoom in using the pinch gesture (even if I explicitly disable zoom in the html code above), but I want the page to be zoomed-in to properly fit the device on load.

Here's the interesting bit... If I put the exact same site on my web server and navigate to it using the default browser on my test device, the page loads properly (scaled to the right size for the device).

Please help.

Thanks.

**EDIT1:**

My current settings are:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,user-scalable=no,target-densitydpi=device-dpi,initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

That too is completely ignored.

**EDIT2:**

Here's something interesting...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

The above line scales the page to 2x in the emulator yet changes nothing on my device (Samsung Epic running 2.2.1). Still though, even at 2x, the page is not being scaled to the emulator's width... I'd have to set that to something like "initial-scale=2.5".

Comment: does adding the initial-scale=1 change anything?

Comment: Hi. my current settings are: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,user-scalable=no,target-densitydpi=device-dpi,initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" /> ... This does nothing. It's completely ignored.Thanks

Comment: You might want to look over my so post here: http://goo.gl/P1nK3, which also points to a defect I filed. It's likely not that they are being ignored, but that the values are conflicting and being dropped. I have lots of results on various permutations of the parameters. You might find something useful. :)

Answer (score 11):

Try adding the following two lines in the onCreate() method of the Java class that extends DroidGap.

```
this.appView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
this.appView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Let me know if your viewport tag now begins to work.

Comment: This is it (and Ivan's answer as well) - this needs millions more upvotes. Although, for me it's the `public class MyApp extends CordovaActivity` method that needs up dating, not `DroidGap`. Maybe you could update your answer because it's still relevant!

Comment: Sorry guys, i'm new to this. Where do i have to add this code, what do i have to do to get my viewport work? I've a cordova 3.6 project and my viewport doesn't work. So... i found this solution and it sounds good but... yep, i don't know where to implement the code. :-/

Comment: Good answer but the API has changed a bit. It's now: ((SystemWebView) appView.getEngine().getView()).getSettings().xxx

Answer (score 2):

I've try

```
this.appView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
this.appView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Zoom is not enabled.

With the following setting, zoom enabled

```
this.appView.getStrings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

But it's not controlled correctly by the viewport tag, all page are zoomable now even with minimum-scale=1 and maximum-scale=1 set in the viewport tag.

And the page navigation got error now, clicking the button on page and the android back button is not working correctly.

Comment: mistake: `this.appView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);`

Answer (score 2):

There are good answers here but the Cordova API seem to have changed a bit.

In the `OnCreate` method (after `loadUrl` or after you call `init` explicitly):

```
    CordovaWebViewEngine engine = appView.getEngine();
    SystemWebView webView = (SystemWebView)engine.getView();
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want android to scale your content to fixed width (1024 in example) use this:

```
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=1024">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewPortWidth = 1024;
    function setViewport() {
    if ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android")!=-1)) {
        var wW0 = window.screen.width;
        var scale = wW0/viewPortWidth;
        var vPort = "width="+viewPortWidth+", maximum-scale="+scale+", minimum-scale="+scale+", initial-scale="+scale+", user-scalable=yes";
        document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", vPort);
    }
    }
    setViewport();
</script>
```

Also, you should add event listener for *onorientationchange* to call setViewport function.

Comment: I had hopes on this but it does not work. My page is 760px and screen is 1080px, it fits with a scale at ~0.465. 760/1080 is ~0.704.

Comment: I *think* the trick here is that not only do you give the `width` attribute, which is supposed to work but apparently doesnt, but also the min-scale, max-scale attributes, which might work instead.

Answer (score -1):

I use this on iphone with phonegap

```
<meta name="description" content="trevorrudolph.com">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta names="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://trevorrudolph.com/wordpress/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

Comment: I believe the issue is android specific though, not iPhone.

Comment: i wrote this long ago before i understood that