# How to make HTML5 app installable on Android Market and Apples AppStore?

Tags: iphone, android, html

I have simple question. I have HTML5 app and I want it to be installable as an ordinary native app. I know there is Titanium Developer and others, but they seem too complicated for this simple task. Is there some simple tool for this problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use phonegap, very very easy,

look at http://www.phonegap.com/start/

you will be given "assets" folder for HTML,CSS,Javascript . Just use those and run.

Comment: Just wanted others to let know, that PhoneGap is really very easy to start making Android apps. However, there are few big problems, you must overcome. Mainly its the scaling problem - good resources are http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916983/android-phonegap-webview-ignores-viewport-meta-tags and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893045/making-sense-of-android-meta-viewport-scaling-what-am-i-missing

Answer (score 2):

I'm just beginning to look at [www.phonegap.com](http://www.phonegap.com) and it's very straightforward...