# Phonegap Android : meta tag "Viewport" is ignored

Tags: android, cordova, viewport

I am using Phonegap 1.4.1 on a Android 2.2 Samsung Galaxy Tab. 
I tried to adjust the viewport with the meta tag `viewport` with `content="width=1024"` but the tag is ignored. 
I already tried solutions like this one
[Android-- PhoneGap/WebView ignores viewport meta tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916983/android-phonegap-webview-ignores-viewport-meta-tags)
But none of the solutions I found so far worked. 
Do you have any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an article saying that the viewport for samsung galaxy tab 7.0 was a bit weird. It display the width as 683px and 330px height. For more details click [here](http://www.sencha.com/blog/samsung-galaxy-android-tablet-the-html5-developer-scorecard/)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

`document.body.style.height = screen.height + 'px';`

in your `onDeviceReady` function.